# Can I use negative lookahead and other conditions together in regex group?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match some URLs against another table using regex and - because the original source wasn't put together properly, I'm using a regex to clean them within the SQL.

As an example, the URLs might be `/this-is-my-test-string/` or `/this-is-my-test-string` and the reference table is always of the form `/this-is-my-test-string` so using this regex works well to capture the matching part.

```
(\/[^\/)]*)\/?
```

However I've now come across some others with the form `/this-is-my-test-string-` and `/this-is-my-test-string-/` which aren't as straightforward - I can't just add `-` to the exclusion as it's present in the rest of the string. From reading around - regex is not something I use regularly - a lookahead would seem to be the answer, but I can't work out how to include this in the expression.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: You do not want a lookahead if you can help it, because then the final slash will not be consumed by the first instance, and it will immediately be triggered in the second instance, if you turn on the /g flag for global matching.  How about using a capture group instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$` to anchor the end of the string, and use a non-greedy quantifier `*?` on the non-slash character set to allow `-?` to match a `-` from (or near) the end of the string:

```
(\/[^\/)]*?)-?\/?$
```